# List ALL Files on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file, detect, nsfilemanager

in Objective C how would I get a list of ALL files on the iPhone?

is this even possible or can I only get files from a certain directory or known path?

Comment: You'll only be able to get files within your sandbox.

Answer (score 6):

Not without jail-breaking your phone. All apps live in a sandbox and can only see certain files.

Answer (score 1):

No you can just get files within your sandbox. And to display your current directory use the following code :

```
- (NSString *) returnFilePath {
    NSArray *pathArray =
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    return [pathArray objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why people are saying that your app can only see certain files inside of your sandbox.  As of iOS 2.x (the last time I tried something like this), you can use [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to list files in almost any directory.  Here is a little code to get **all** of the names of all files in a specific directory.

```
- (NSArray *)allFiles:(NSString *)aPath
    NSMutableArray * listing = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray * fileNames = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:aPath error:nil];
    if (!fileNames) return listing;
    for (NSString * file in fileNames) {
        NSString * absPath = [aPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
        BOOL isDir = NO;
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:absPath isDirectory:&isDir]) {
            if (isDir) {
                [listing addObject:absPath];
                [listing addObjectsFromArray:[self allFiles:absPath]];
            } else {
                [listing addObject:absPath];
            }
        }
    }
    return listing;
}
```

This is an example of a very simple recursive function.  It could, of course be modified to work more efficiently with blocks as callbacks or even incorporate `NSOperation`.

Comment: Sorry, replace `startPath` (the argument passed) with `aPath`